# Dynamically set join type in mysql through php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 table with following structure

**products**

```
    [id]    [name]          [setting_id]
    1       pendrive            6
    2       laptop              3
    3       mobile              2
    4       vallet              7
    5       clothes             4
```

**store_product**

```
[id]            [name]          [storeid]
    2       laptop_store        1
    3       mobile_mobile       1
    5       clothes_store       4
    8       new1_store          2
    9       new2_store          3
```

I want result like this

```
    [id]    [name]
    1       pendrive
    2       laptop_store
    3       mobile_mobile
    4       vallet
    5       clothes_store
    8       new1_store
    9       new2_store
```

I have tried this query but it gives only but there is no new1_store and new1_store

```
    SELECT products.id , CASE WHEN store_product.name IS NOT NULL AND  store_product.name!='' THEN  store_product.name ELSE products.name END AS name 
    from products 
    left join store_product on store_product.id = products.id
```

As I know from left join it is not possible but can please suggest any optimized query (Avoid union of left join and right join) .If possible than please answer

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In MS-SQL Server, I would resolve this with the following query:

```
Select Id, Name from Products P
Where Not Exists (Select * from Store_Product SP where SP.Id = P.Id)
Union All
Select Id, Name from Store_Product
```

For MySQL, I don't know.

Comment: nice answer... but is it is possible without union??.. thnks

Comment: You don't want an Union and you don't want a combination of Left and Right Outer Join neither.  I'm sorry to say that but it's your design that is faulty.  You should have only one table for the various products, with proper fields to differentiate between their types.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this below. 
First part selects ids and names for products existing in `products` table and possibly in `store_product` table. 
Second part fills the ids and names of rows with ids existing only in `store_product` table.

```
(SELECT products.id, COALESCE(store_product.name, products.name) as name
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN store_product ON store_product.id = products.id)

UNION

(SELECT store_product.id, store_product.name as name
FROM store_product 
LEFT JOIN products ON store_product.id = products.id
WHERE products.id IS NULL)

ORDER BY id
```

Comment: this is correct answer...but as I specified in Question I want to avoid union ...because I have large table so union gives so much load on server....if possible than please suggest ...anyway Thanks for quick answer

Comment: If you want to avoid union you'd have to do another JOIN, which I believe could give more load to the server. Try querying `EXPLAN (quere from above here)` and post the results, it'll be a good hint if it actually has low performance.